# SQL Server - multi tenancy, restrict usage of tables

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, multi-tenant

We are using SQL Server multi-tenancy using views.

All our stored procedures use only views and tables are completely restricted.

We use grant execute permission to all our stored procedures to execute.

To restrict our developers not to use any tables instead of views, can we have a rule or constraint or check which stops creating or altering stored procedures with tables.

Please provide your suggestions.

Comment: You don't have a DEV or TEST environment outside of your PROD?  That cannot be a good thing at all.  Chasing permissions as to whether George or Johan can do something or not is a security nightmare!

Answer (score 0):

[DDL Triggers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175941(v=sql.110).aspx)

Example:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER safety 
ON DATABASE 
FOR DROP_TABLE, ALTER_TABLE 
AS 
   PRINT 'You must disable Trigger "safety" to drop or alter tables!' 
   ROLLBACK;
```